# can appcelerator connect to asmx web services?

Tags: javascript, asmx, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to build a simple login form  for Iphone\Android in appcelerator-Titanium that would connect to an existing asmx web service (.net).
is there an exisitng hello world or a sample for that?

Comment: Titanium supports the web services..you can see this example:  https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/tree/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples

Comment: hello dear..have u create a login form in appcelratore usin asmx services??i am new on titinuim appcelerator,can u please share the sample code with me?it would be very kind of u.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KitchenSinks [suds.js](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/suds.js) client to [connect](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/soap.js) or you can write your own. For the login form there is a decent tutorial on [titanium user authentication](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-user-authentication/).

Also this super helpful [guide](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+Remote+Data) may assist you.